# What is an invasion?

Tags: puzzle-and-dragons

I've heard of invasions happening, like Spirit Jewels invading some place as a news event, but I ignored it because I was such a low level. I want a Keeper of Light, and, according to Puzzle Dragon X, they appear as an Invade in the expert floors of [Tuesday Dungeon](http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/mission.asp?m=59). What does "Invade" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An invade is an uncommon event for some dungeons in which the normal monsters for that floor are gone and *replaced* by the monster that is marked as an "Invade".  So, in your case, if you are lucky and/or run the Tuesday dungeons enough, occasionally a floor will have a single Keeper of Light and nothing else, which will drop if defeated.

Invades can occur on any floor except for the boss (final) floor.  This does mean that they can even replace fixed encounters, such as the Flame Knight on [Keeper of the Red](http://www.puzzledragonx.com/en/mission.asp?m=59).  They can even replace otherwise very powerful monsters in Descended dungeons, but those invades are themselves very powerful.

Note that invades always have a 100% drop rate, but they don't necessarily drop the actual monster you face.  For example, the Spirit Jewel invasions force you to fight a monster from the Chinese Gods series, but when defeated they will drop a Spirit Jewel - a high-end evolution material.